# How can i lock a screen in a certain position (javafx)?

Tags: java, javafx

i have to make a game for a school project and i was wondering if it's possible to lock a screen in a certain position on the screen. I have a settings button that opens a new stage and i want to make that scene immovable   is this possible?

This is the code where i display the settings screen:

```
Public void buttonAction(){
        btnSettings.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                GridPane settingsGrid = new GridPane();
                Scene scene1 = new Scene(settingsGrid,375,600);
                Stage settingsStage = new Stage();
                settingsGrid.setHgap(10);
                settingsGrid.setVgap(10);
                //settingsGrid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
                settingsStage.setTitle("Settings");
                settingsStage.setResizable(false);
                settingsStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                settingsStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                settingsStage.setScene(scene1);
                settingsStage.showAndWait();
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please refrain from posting codes as images and stick to text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
        settingsStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

However, you could only have one initStyle if I remember correctly. So you have to                 settingsStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY); in order to use the above code. What it does is it make the background transparent and the user could not change the position.

Comment: By using Alt+Space+M, we can move the screen if we use this code.